# Using "dispose()" on a Music object inside its "OnCompletionListener()"?

Tags: java, audio, libgdx, dispose

It seemed like a good idea to have a Music object `dispose()` of itself when its song ended. Just call `individual_Music.dispose()` in the Music object's `OnCompletionListener()`, right? Well, that has not worked so well.

I declare the following earlier in the file:

```
private Music musicMoment = Gdx.audio.newMusic( Gdx.files.internal( "music/blank.ogg" ) );
```

The following method sets up the listener:

```
void music_Setup_for_One_File() {

    musicMoment.setVolume( 0.6f );

    musicMoment.setOnCompletionListener( new Music.OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion( Music musicTest ) {

            musicMoment.dispose();
            musicTest.dispose();

            System.out.println( "TEST test Moo!!!!");

        }

    });

}
```

I use the following method to see if `musicMoment` is null or not when the program comes to a close:

```
final void dispose_of_Single_Music_Song_Before_It_Finishes() {

    boolean test = false;


    if ( musicMoment != null ) {

        musicMoment.dispose();
        System.out.println( "'musicMoment' song disposed of from memory." );

    } else {

        System.out.println( "There is no need to clear 'musicMoment'.  It is already null." );

    }

}
```

The code above always shows the Music object, `musicMoment`, as not null. The software may run several seconds, and even though " blank.ogg " lasts less than a second, this seems to stay true each time. Calling `dispose()` outside of the listener works fine, so 'musicMoment' appears null then.

How do I properly dispose of the song when it ends, if `dispose()` does not work inside the listener?

Comment: Why do you think calling `dispose()` on it would set it to `null`?

Comment: @David  I checked your logic, and it seems it does not.  I was thinking of how `null` can relate to garbage collection in standard Java.  So if `null` does not indicate a successful `dispose()` from LibGDX, what should I check for?

Comment: I don't think there's anything you need to check for (or can), at least as far as I can tell from reading [the documentation](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/audio/Music.html). (I suppose you could try to play it again, and see that it (presumably) gives you some error.)

Comment: @David  Okay, thank you for your insight.  It still plays anyway, even with `dispose()` called before `play()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dispose()` will not clear reference of any object. If you don't have reference of any object that might be cleared from heap memory when garbage collector run.

According to doc, Heavy resources like `Images and sound effects` managed by native drivers instead of Java garbage collector.

Those resources need to be manually disposed when your resource no longer needed. All those resources implement a common interface [Disposable](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Disposable.html).

**Failure to dispose resources will lead to severe memory leaks!.**

Resources should be disposed of as soon as they are no longer needed, freeing up memory associated with them. Accessing a disposed resource will result in undefined errors, so make sure to `clear out all references you have to a disposed resource`.

Comment: So would it be fine to `dispose()` the Music object before changing the variable to a different Music object?  There would be no other references to my knowledge.

Comment: when no longer needed first dispose his allocated resources(vram data) using `dispose()` then assign reference to `null` so that will be ready for garbage collector.

Comment: I use a playlist, so the `Music` variable changes references about every 2 to 3 minutes.  I assume this would have the same effect as setting it to `null`?